# What is this type of aircraft?

Tags: aircraft-design, airliner, aircraft-identification

[image]

In this picture, could anyone describe what type of aircraft and which airline it is?

Comment: Any type of information on what flight this was? Or source of the picture?

Comment: The background is pretty clearly downtown New York; if nothing else, the Empire State building should be a dead giveaway.

Comment: That area in the photo is better described as Midtown South.  Downtown is the collection of highrises just below the wing.  -Skip Miller

Answer (score 16):

That's a [US Airways Embraer E190](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:US_Airways_N967UW_Embraer_190.jpg)

[Here is another view of the E190 wing](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Embraer_190_-_Wing_and_winglet.jpg) for comparison.

Comment: And sadly, CRJ production is winding down toward the end of this year so Embraer pretty much has the market all to itself, perhaps until the Mitsubishi RJ is certified.

Comment: @JohnK not so much. The A2xx series from Airbus is what was previously the C-jet series Bombardier designed to replace the CRJ in production.

Comment: No the C series is a larger airplane and was not intended as an RJ replacement. It was a bridge between the Regionals and the smaller narrowbodies.  The E jets pretty much have the 70-90 seat market to themselves notwithstanding minor players like Sukhoi.